# ionic, android 11, cordova_file_plugin, app folder is not accessible

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I'm using cordova_file_plugin to save a file on the device, the problem is that the application folder in Android/Data is hidden and not accessible from the file manager.
Is there any way to access the app folder or save the file in another public folder? I'm using `externalDataDirectory`

```
this.file.writeFile(this.file.externalDataDirectory, fileName, csv, {replace: true})
      .then(
        res => {
          const msg = 'Die CSV-Datei wurde erfolgreich exportiert und ist unter "Eigene Dateien" ' +
            'auf Ihrem Gerät verfügbar.';
          this.toastsService.showSuccessMessage(msg);
        }
      )
}
```

Comment: Do you mean /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<packagename> folder? Then please say so. Your app has access there so you can aleays list all files.

Comment: @blackapps, yes that's exactly the directory, and yes the app can access and write files there and I can access the folder from PC by connecting the device by cable or by using an external file manager.

Comment: Why are you using this.file.externalDataDirectory then? There are more directories on this.file.

Comment: @blackapps All are the same, they all save the file in the app folder in Android/Data.
I tried to use all the methods and non of them gave me a different result.

Comment: Please show all others like this.file.externalDataDirectory. As we do noy know what you tried if you keep it vague.

Comment: I tried applicationDirectory, applicationStorageDirectory, dataDirectory, and externalApplicationStorageDirectory

Comment: Are they all? Pretty strange that you can choose so many locations while they would lead to the same storage location. Hard to believe.

Comment: All the supported locations are listed here in the android section
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/reference/cordova-plugin-file/

Comment: Quote from your link: `(on Android, if you need to use external memory, use .externalDataDirectory).` So it is strange that that did not work. Schade!

Comment: Try externalRootDirectory. And on Android 11+ externalRootDirectory/Documents.

Comment: It saves the file in SDCard

Comment: No. It will not. You did not even try it. And if it did... What would be the problem?

Comment: The documentation says that
`cordova.file.externalRootDirectory - External storage (SD card) root. (Android, BlackBerry 10)`

and the problem is that most people don't use SD Cards

Comment: My god i read that documentation too. Try it . use it.. It will not use the removable micro sd card. You did not even try it!

Comment: I tried it, but this time I got an error `INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR`.
Note: I added the permissions of read/write external storage in Android.Manifest.xml

Comment: And what does that mean? Again: Tell better what you do and tried. `Try externalRootDirectory. And on Android 11+ externalRootDirectory/Documents.` I dont know what you tried where. Show full code before you post an error.

Comment: Adding permissiion requests to manifest file is not enough as you should know. Again: I dont know what you did further.

Comment: Maan! You are right :) It worked after adding '/Documents' and the files are saved directly in the Documents folder. You saved my day.  Please add your comment as an answer to mark it as the correct answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the comments.